# How to remove "Tags:" from get_tags() output

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

I am working on a website with WordPress and wanted to display the tags associated with a post by using the function:

```
get_tags();
```

But instead of displaying just the tags for a post, this function also outputed the text "Tags:" before all of the tags displayed. I want to change this text to something a little more modern like an icon or just get rid of it all-together. Is there some kind of argument that I can pass to this function to achieve my goal, if not, what can I do? Here is a snippet of my code from "single.php":

```
<h4 class="singleposttags"><?php the_tags(); ?></h4>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the first parameter

```php
the_tags('<i class="your-icon"></i> ');
```

It should allow you to use HTML string as a parameter. Read more https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_tags/

And then style

```css
.your-icon {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this one and I hope it will definitely work.

```
the_tags('<span class="class_name"></span> ');

<style>
    .class_name
    {
    //Your css attributes will be here.
    }
</style>
```